# Infinite scrolling with div own

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, infinity

First thanks for the help , I 'm with a problem I can not solve. I have this script which is infinite , however I want it to be infinite using typical of the #main divs , example :

I have divs

```
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
```

first rises to 5, then 4 , then 3 and so on, endlessly rising from the bottom up , how to accomplish this ?

```
           infinitely rising <----------------------
<div class="content">3</div> the third to go up --| | 
<div class="content">4</div> the second to rise --| | 
<div class="content">5</div> the first to rise  --  |
           ....                                     |
<div class="content">2</div> -----------------------
<div class="content">3</div> after you [...]
<div class="content">4</div> after you
<div class="content">5</div> first climbs you
```

my script http://jsfiddle.net/66RvC/70/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but just made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6un8L1aL/)

```
function cycle() {
  var dLength = $("div.content").size();
  $(".content").eq(dLength - 1).prependTo($("#main"));
  setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
}

cycle();
```

based on the assumption that you want a fixed set of divs infinitely rising up/changing places, and this adjustment of your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3688cvdj/) - only changed this function:

```
var d = function(){
  var dLength = $("div.content").size();
  return $(".content").eq(dLength - (i++)).clone();
};
```

in case you want to add infinite copies/clones of the divs instead.